# Joomla: How to check if admin is logged in

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla3.0

I've added a custom PHP page which does not use any Joomla component.
I made changes inside .htaccess so the page is now accessible.

the link will be like http://www.example.com/administrator/mypage.php

But the page is accessible by everyone without logging in to admin panel.
How can I make it only view-able by Admin?

My Joomla version is 3.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your php page must include the joomla framework or you will not able to use any of the joomla functions.

I usually use this snippet of code at beginning of the php file (the php file is in the root directory):

```
 define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

 define('JPATH_BASE', './' ); //config this as you need

 define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
 require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
 require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

 JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark( 'afterLoad' ) : null;
 $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
 $mainframe->initialise();
 JPluginHelper::importPlugin('system');
 JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null;
 $mainframe->triggerEvent('onAfterInitialise');

// Get user
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if ($user->authorise('core.admin')) {
//your code here

}
```

Remember that this is not a correct solution, you should create a component for joomla to extend it. Custom php pages can create security issues.

Hope it helps,
Marco